# Generate Unique 4-digit random number without using Random class

Tags: java, random, unique

I need help in generating a 4-digit random number between 1-8 without using the random class OR the collections.shuffle().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use Math.random()?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Yes I can use Math.random and ai tried it as well. but it gave me duplicates once in a while.

Comment: use SecureRandom instead

Comment: I am a student and we haven't yet gotten to the point where all of the above start (Random, Collections.shuffle, Secure Random, etc).
Means we have not been taught this yet.

Comment: Then there is no way. To generate a truly random number, you must communicate with hardware components. This is done by the methods that were mentioned here. There is no mathematic way to generate a random number.

Comment: i doubt your teacher is expecting you to reinvent the weel (i.e. make your own algorithm). That would be quite complex task. Just use the Random class.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I don't know how to properly use the Random class and if he asks how come I used that and what (else) this class does, I would not be able to answer clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you can do it:

- Generate an array of 0 - 9.
- Randomly shuffle the array.
- Pick the first four element from the array to construct the 4-digit number.

---

```
int[] nums = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

//Shuffle array
for(int x=0; x<nums.length; x++){
    int i = (int)(Math.random()*10);  //generate random 0-9
    int temp = nums[x];
    nums[x] = nums[i];
    nums[i] = temp;
}
```

From the shuffled array, simply get the first 4 elements and construct your unique number.

Comment: But to randomly shuffle an array, you still are going to have to use Math.Random or SecureRandom.

Comment: May I please ask for an example of how to shuffle.

Comment: I can use math.random but not the Random class

Comment: @Ash See my updated solution above. You can use `(int)(Math.random()*10);` to generate random array index of `0-9`.

Comment: This is called a "naive shuffle" and is **not** a good solution for shuffling, not all permutations are equally likely.  See [this blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) for a nice explanation.  You should use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle), or some variant.

Comment: @Peter O. Thanks for the change, so now this solution is using Fisher-Yates shuffle already?

Comment: @user3437460: Yes it did. But I rolled it back, unfortunately. Because this is a question about the asker's coursework, making an edit like this at this time may be improper, it seems to me.  It may be reinstated when enough time passes.